# Way to change direction of risk difference in proc freq, without changing data in SAS

Tags: sas

Suppose I have a dataset called `example` with variable `x` and `y`, where both are binary {0,1}. I want to find the risk difference stratified by a variable `strata`.

```
proc freq data = example;
    table strata*x*y / commonriskdiff(CL=NEWCOMBEMR);
run;
```

[image]

However, suppose I want them in different direction, i.e., I want `0.004 (-0.017, 0.028)`

I can do

```
data example2;
    set example;
    y_2 = 1 - y;
run;
proc freq data = example2;
    table strata*x*y_2 / commonriskdiff(CL=NEWCOMBEMR);
run;
```

but is there a way to do it directly on `proc freq`, without the extra step of creating `example2` dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

commonriskdiff(CL=NEWCOMBEMR **column = 2**)